# how to show a user the values he chose in some drop-down menus on the submit event in case of mistake

Tags: php, jquery

I need some help because I modified a jQuery script to obtain some drop-down menus that are linked together, from a form of mine. I have a PHP script with 3 different tables on my MySQL database, to let a user choose his region, then with a Ajax call that I do with the jQuery script, I show him only the provinces that belong to that chosen region, and once he chooses the province, I show him only the towns that belong to this province in a similar way.

All is ok up to that, but I'd like to do something more: that's to say, if the user forgets to fill in some obligatory fields, (I control all the fields with PHP) when he clicks on submit, I would manage to show him also these three drop-down menus that maybe he has filled, with the choices he has made, without forcing him to fill in the three selects once again.

I got no problem in doing that for all the other fields with PHP, but here I use a Ajax call with a jQuery script and I'd like to do it just inside this jQuery script.

Here is my script and I miss the final part, as you can see, on the submit event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var scegli = '<option value="0">Scegli...</option>';
    var attendere = '<option value="0">Attendere...</option>';

    $("select#province").html(scegli);
    $("select#province").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("select#comuni").html(scegli);
    $("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");



    $("select#regioni").change(function(){
        var regione = $("select#regioni option:selected").attr('value');
        $("select#province").html(attendere);
        $("select#province").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("select#comuni").html(scegli);
        $("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        $.post("select.php", {id_reg:regione}, function(data){
            $("select#province").removeAttr("disabled"); 
            $("select#province").html(data);    
        });
    }); 



    $("select#province").change(function(){
        $("select#comuni").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("select#comuni").html(attendere);
        var provincia = $("select#province option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select.php", {id_pro:provincia}, function(data){
            $("select#comuni").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#comuni").html(data);  
        });
    }); 



    $("#form_registrazione").submit(function(){
        var reg = $("select#regioni option:selected").attr('value');  
        var prov = $("select#province option:selected").attr('value');  
        var com = $("select#comuni option:selected").attr('value');  


        if ( reg > 0 && prov > 0 && com > 0 )
// I miss here the final part

});
```

Here's the link to my page of [website](http://newbielinux.altervista.org/registrazione.php): it's only in Italian, but nonetheless you can see the undesired behavior I described above, if you make a mistake filling in an obligatory field of the form and you try to send it out.

Thanks for your help.
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I updated the code

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#username').val() == '' ||  $('#password').val() == '') {
        alert('alert - Required fields');
        $('#username').css('border-color','red');
        $('#password').css('border-color','red');
    } else {
        $('#form_registrazione').submit();
    }
});
jQuery.each($('.required'), function () {
        $(this).on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('glowing-border').removeClass('red');
        });
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coscho/AUM86/5/)

**OR** you can use a [jQuery validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. In fact I don't know how to tell the script to show the possible choices made by a user after submitting my form. That way he doesn't have to repeat his choices once again.

Comment: I understand now what you want. Actualy your form is refreshing. And the validation is given by php. Am I right?  If so you can check if the requird fields are filled before submit. I'll update de code.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but it doesn't work yet. As you said all the fields are controlled and validated via server side with PHP! Doing that is the only way to be sure from surprises that a user could use in a form! I always do that for my forms in my websites!

Comment: I just need to submit this form with the values chosen maybe by a user, I mean the values of these 3 drop-down menus, which are optional fields, to be able to show him this form again with the choices he made before, avoiding him the hassle to choose again from these 3 drop-down menus. Bye.

Comment: To understand well what I mean, just have a try with my form. Fill in the fields except one of those required (they have the sign *) of course, and make your choices in the 3 drop-down menus, and then click on submit (the button below with the word Invia), and you'll see a box above the form telling you, you missed one obligatory field, which will be also emphasized by a red box, and all the values you wrote, will be shown but for the 3 drop-down menus. You'll have to choose from these again, if you wish to send this values, of course. That's what I'm not able to retrieve. The link is above.

Comment: I add this link also here [link]http://newbielinux.altervista.org/registrazione.php to make it easier!. Bye.

Comment: Hi Hatt. I updated the code please check Jsfiddle link. Is exactly what you need. You can contact me on skype: florinmarina.

Comment: Is better to keep php validation. jQuery makes just warnings. Real validtion is made by php. Is good to have both validation on a php website

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the results I wish following the new solution you proposed on Jsfiddle. If you miss filling in one obligatory field and you choose the values in the 3 drop-down menus and then you submit the form, the values of these menus are not shown anymore as I would like to obtain. All other fields are present instead with the values you wrote before, as you can see, if you just give a try. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Matt. This is exatcyly what you need. Did you put in condition all required field that you need?

Comment: I'm sorry but the code you wrote on jsFiddle doesn't return the values of the 3 drop-down menus after submitting the form!. As I said if you send the form missing one required field and you make your choices in the 3 menus, the form is presented to you again with all values you wrote except for the 3 menus!. I'm not able to retrieve these values the way you proposed there on jsFiddle.Bye.